# PHP Random Math Quiz Evaluation issue

Tags: php

EDIT: When I print the $answer variable by itself it always returns the correct answer of the current question.

I am currently coding a PHP script that produces a simple, but completely random math quiz. How it works is that is gets two random numbers between 0-9 and a random operator from '-', '+', '*'. The user must enter into the text box the answer of the shown question. From here it's pretty straightforward to understand.

However, the issue I am having is that no matter what the user enters the only questions that are validated as correct are ones where the answer is 0.

Here is my code so far.

```
<?php

require 'functions.php';

$body = "";  

$score = 0;
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstDigit = $_POST['lho'];
    $secondDigit = $_POST['rho'];
    $operator = $_POST['op'];
    $userAnswer = $_POST['answer'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    $answer = evaluate($firstDigit, $secondDigit, $operator);

    if($answer == $userAnswer)
    {
        $count++;
        $score++;
        $body .= "\n<h1>Congratulations!</h1>\n\n";
        $body .= "$score out of $count";
    }
    else
    {   
        $count++;
        $body .= "\n<h1>Sorry!</h1>\n\n";
        $body .= "$score out of $count";
    }
}

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n");

?>

<?php
    include("./header.php");
?>

<h1>Math Quiz</h1> <br /> <br />

<?php 
    print $body;
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <h3><?php echo $firstDigit; ?> <?php echo $operator; ?> <?php echo $secondDigit; ?> = ? 
        <input type="text" name="answer" size="2" /></h3>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Try It!" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lho" value="<?php echo randdigit(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rho" value="<?php echo randdigit(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="<?php echo randop(); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="score" value="<?php echo $score++; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $count++; ?>" /></p>
</form>

<?php
    include("./footer.php");
?>
```

My evaluate function is this:

```
function evaluate($d1, $d2, $op) {
    switch($op) {
        case '+' : // addition
            $result = $d1 + $d2;
            break;
        case '-' : // subtraction
            $result = $d1 - $d2;
            break;
        case '*' : // multiplication
            $result = $d1 * $d2;
            break;
        default :  // Unidentified, return safe value
            $result = 0;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here is the randop() function and the randdigit() function:

```
/* Return a number in the range 0-9 inclusive
 */
function randdigit() {
    return mt_rand(0,9);
} // end functionranddigit()

function randop(){
    $ops = array('+', '-', '*');
    // pick a random index between zero and highest index in array.
    $randnum = mt_rand(0,sizeof($ops)-1);
    return $ops[$randnum];  // Use the index to pick the operator
}
```

Comment: try printing the expected answer everytime to see why the comparaison doesn't work

Comment: The problem *appears* to be with your `$operator` / `$_POST['op']` variable, which is undefined. It is correctly set up in your form as `name="op"`, but it comes from `randop()`, and you don't appear to have this function. If you do have this function set up, can you please include the code for it?

Comment: Do you get the correct output in your h3?  Have you done what Liora suggested?

Comment: Yes, I've outputted the $answer variable on it's own. Each iteration of it is always the correct value of the current question.

Comment: Try to cast the $answer and the $userAnswer to ints

Comment: @alanfcm Just tried that. The same issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First on the 48th line :

```
<h3><?php echo $firstDigit; ?> <?php echo $operator; ?> <?php echo $secondDigit; ?> = ?
```

When you first load the form and until it has been submitted once,

> $firstDigit, $operator, $secondDigit

Aren't set.

Then, this line wich is the equation to solve is filled with the old equation that needed to be solved AND your hidden fields are filled with new numbers, invisible to the user using randdigit() and randop().

```
<input type="hidden" name="lho" value="<?php echo randdigit(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="rho" value="<?php echo randdigit(); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="op" value="<?php echo randop(); ?>" />
```

Here is the code that works well for me :

```
<?php

require 'functions.php';

$body = "";  

$score = 0;
$count = 0;
$newFdigit = randdigit();
$newSdigit = randdigit();
$newOperator = randop();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $firstDigit = $_POST['lho'];
    $secondDigit = $_POST['rho'];
    $operator = $_POST['op'];
    $userAnswer = $_POST['answer'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    $answer = evaluate($firstDigit, $secondDigit, $operator);

    if($answer == $userAnswer)
    {
        $count++;
        $score++;
        $body .= "\n<h1>Congratulations!</h1>\n\n";
        $body .= "$score out of $count";
    }
    else
    {   
        $count++;
        $body .= "\n<h1>Sorry!</h1>\n\n";
        $body .= "$score out of $count";
    }
}

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n");

?>


<h1>Math Quiz</h1> <br /> <br />

<?php 
    print $body;
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <h3><?php echo $newFdigit; ?> <?php echo $newOperator; ?> <?php echo $newSdigit; ?> = ? 
        <input type="text" name="answer" size="2" /></h3>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Try It!" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lho" value="<?php echo $newFdigit ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rho" value="<?php echo $newSdigit; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="op" value="<?php echo $newOperator; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="score" value="<?php echo $score++; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php echo $count++; ?>" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Btw you should turn on php error display and make it report everything when you get into something like this. This won't trigger an error but you would've got a few notices. Either do it in your php.ini or use those 3 lines of code, that can save you quite some time :
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the issue. I really appreciate the help.